# Creating a FizzBuzz Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, object, fizzbuzz

I am trying to attempt to create a fizzbuzz class, however I feel as though I am not fully understanding how classes and objects in Ruby work.

This is the problem I'm trying to solve is as follows:

Build a class called FizzBuzz that takes two numbers as parameters and then have a method called run that returns a fizzbuzz array (numbers from 1 to 100, numbers divisible by the first number replaced by 'fizz' and numbers replaced by the second number replaced by 'buzz' and numbers divisible by both replaced by 'fizzbuzz'). For instance this code should work with your class:

```
fb = FizzBuzz.new(3,5)
fb.run # returns an array like: [1, 2, 'fizz', 4, 'buzz, ..]
```

and afterwards I am required to modify my solution to make it flexible and be able to change the numbers after I create the object. i'm not so worried about this part at the moment!

here is what I have so far:

```
class FizzBuzz(num1, num2)
  def run
    nums = [1..100]
    for i in nums
      if i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0
        puts "fizbuzz"
      elsif i % num1 == 0 
        puts "fizz"
      elsif i % num2 == 0
        puts "buzz"
      else puts i
    end
  end
end

fb = FizzBuzz.new(3, 5)
fb.run
```

Cheers,

Brandyn

Comment: Is there any reason in implementing the algorithm like this apart from the fact that this the idea that you first stumbled on to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimum changes to your code that will make it work:

```
class FizzBuzz
  attr_reader :num1, :num2

  def initialize(num1, num2)
    @num1, @num2 = num1, num2
  end

  def run
    1.upto(100).each do |i|
      if i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0
        puts "fizbuzz"
      elsif i % num1 == 0
        puts "fizz"
      elsif i % num2 == 0
        puts "buzz"
      else puts i
      end
    end
  end
end

fb = FizzBuzz.new(3, 5)
fb.run
```

First of all, you should define constructor( `.initialize` ) method which will accept your `num1` and `num2` arguments, then, to use inside a class, I am assigning them to instance variables(with prefix `@`). To read them without this prefix(in `run`), I am defining `attr_reader :num1, :num2` which simply creates 2 methods to access those instance variables. And finally, in Ruby, we prefer iterators to cycles, so I replaced your `for` with `upto`

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the array with fizz and buzz, but what you're currently doing is just `puts` which will output the words but not modify the array, the return array will still be the array 1..100.
Also [1..100] is an array of a single range, not an array of a 100 numbers.
To be able to initialize with two parameters you need an initialize function, then save those two numnbers as instance variables.
*EDIT: I extraced the fizzbuzz logic into a separate method, and used `map` to call this method for each number.*
So after those modifications your code will look like this

```
class FizzBuzz
  def initialize(num1, num2)
    @n1 = num1
    @n2 = num2
  end
  def run
    nums = (1..100).to_a
    nums.map {|n| fizz_or_buzz(n,@n1,@n2)} 
  end

  def fizz_or_buzz(number, n1, n2)
    if number % n1 == 0 && number % n2 == 0
      'fizzbuzz'
    elsif number % n1 == 0
      'fizz'
    elsif number % n2 == 0
      'buzz'
    else
      number
    end
  end

end

fb = FizzBuzz.new(3, 5)
fb.run
```

To be able to modify those values you could create a new method called `change` for example, which will replace the two instance variables

```
def change(n1, n2)
  @num1 = n1;
  @num2 = n2;
end
```

then run

```
fb.change(1,2)
fb.run
```

Comment: thank you mohammed.. could you (or anyone for that matter) please explain to me why we use the instance variables in the run method but not the fizz_or_buzz method??

Comment: well you want to create an instance of `fb` this instance should remember the numbers you gave it at the beginning every time, so you could run `run` as many times without needing to give it the two numbers, so to save those numbers you create `instance` variablesm the other method `fizz_or_buzz` doesn't need to remember any thing, it recieves the variables and returns the result at the same time, so I don't need it to remember any thing.